# Segmentation and Granulometry with scikit-image

Tags: python, image, analysis, image-segmentation

I am very interested in python image analysis and especially in Scikit-image.

As a newbie would it be possible to get an explanation how to convert the Matlab codes below to python+scikit-image.

Detecting a Cell Using Image Segmentation

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detecting-a-cell-using-image-segmentation.html

Granulometry of Snowflakes

http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexsnow.html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Java with Fiji or ImageJ instead.
there are plenty of built in tools in Fiji for what you 
are looking to do.  It is much easier to build a macro in Fiji
out of the built in plugins and tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you need tool for sophisticated cell image analysis, be familiar with Cellprofiler. It can segment images and calculate their object features as you has showed.

Scikit-image has relevant code samples in gallery: [watershed segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_watershed.html) and [labeling](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_label.html).